# temporarily disable hotkey during gaming

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

I just got window 8 with new laptop (sadly, and yuck this OS sucks, if it wasn't for gaming I would so switch to ubuntu).  I've been systematically disabling and changing settings till I have almost gotten it to a working OS.

My current issue is with the new hotkeys, most notably window + D.  I play MMO with many hot keys mapped to to speed up activating them, and ALT+D is a major one, so I'm not happey when my finger slips to window+D and I toggle out of the game only to come back to everyone dead.  I want to prevent this toggling while I have a game open.

Ideally, I like to know if there is a way to keep the shortcut, but just disable it when I have an app running in full screen mode open, or even disable it only for certain apps.  Failing that I would settle for a way to either re-map the hotkey or remove it entirely.

can anyone help me?  a dead raid thanks to window's 8 will thank you.

Comment: Windows + D has been in Windows for a while now, it's not Windows 8 specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [WKey Disabler](https://wkeydisabler.codeplex.com/) to temporarily disable the Windows key. If you're willing to learn some scripting with [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm), it's trivial to disable the key automatically when certain programs are running.

Comment: I'm sorry it took so long to reply, but thank you very much.  AutoHotKey has not only removed the toggle problem, it now maps windows to Alt, so I will activiate my abilities easier, and allowed me to fix an annoyance with SWOTR (that I can't map ctrl+space or shift+space).  AND when I realized I had to use windowed mode I learned that toggling is so much easier in windowed mode, should have done that long ago :)

Comment: For anyone who goes the AutoHotKey route It worked great..after a bit of effort.  First, you have to run your MMO in Windowed mode (check prefernces).  Then You must run AutoHotKey as admin, here a helpfull link:  http://blog.danskingdom.com/get-autohotkey-script-to-run-as-admin-at-startup/  Finally your want to use the IfWinActive with ahk_class PlayerClient (I think PlayerClient applies to all MMO but can't test that).  here my final file: note I mapped all the ctrl-space and shift-space to ctrl-L and shift-L so that I could then map those to abilities in game.

Comment: #IfWinActive, ahk_class PlayerClient

LWin::Alt
^Space::^L
!Space::!L
+Space::+L

#IfWinActive

Answer (score 1):

AutoHotKey is an excellent tool, but if all you want to do is disable one key, it's clearly overkill.

WKey Disabler was a much simpler solution. Unfortunately, the project is archived, and we can't download the application anymore.

Let me suggest another open-source application that I created:

> https://bblanchon.github.io/disable-windows-keys/

The principle is the same as WKey Disabler: open the app to disable the Windows keys, close it to restore them.

[image]

Unlike WKey Disabler, it's a native application, and therefore, has a minimal footprint.